# Как называется принцип, реализованный в приведенном коде?

Tags: c++

Не могу найти, как называется принцип, реализованный в приведенном ниже коде:

**ILog** является абстрактным классом, который является общедоступным (программист может подключить этот класс к своему проекту).

**`ilog.h`**

```cpp
class ILog {
public:
    ILog() = default;
    ILog& operator=(const ILog& other) = default;
    ILog& operator=(ILog&& other) = default;
    ILog(const ILog& other) = default;
    ILog(ILog&& other) = default;
    virtual ~ILog() = default;

    virtual void write(const quint32& level, const QString& message) noexcept = 0;

    // Реализовано в скрытом классе для программиста.
    static ILog* createInstance() noexcept;
};
```

**BaseLog** реализовывает `write` метод и `createInstance`. Данный класс скрыт от программиста (подключить его при помощи `include` в свой проект нельзя).

**`baseLog.h`**

```cpp
class BaseLog : public ILog {
public:
    BaseLog();
    BaseLog& operator=(const BaseLog& other) = default;
    BaseLog& operator=(BaseLog&& other) = default;
    BaseLog(const BaseLog& other) = default;
    BaseLog(BaseLog&& other) = default;
    virtual ~BaseLog() = default;

    void write(const quint32& level, const QString& message) noexcept override;
};
```

**`baseLog.cpp`**

```cpp
void BaseLog::write(const quint32& level, const QString& message) noexcept
{
    // ...
}

BaseLog::BaseLog()
    : ILog()
{
}

ILog* ILog::createInstance() noexcept
{
    return new BaseLog;
}
```

И теперь мы можем использовать наш `Logger`. Пример приведен в `main.cpp`:

**`main.cpp`**

```cpp
#include "ilog.h"

int main()
{
    ILog* log = ILog::createInstance();
    
    log->write(1, "Example");

    // ...

    delete log;
    
}
```

Также меня интересует, популярен ли этот принцип и в каких случаях лучше всего его использовать.

*PS* **Важно отметить, что при использовании этого принципа при создании статической библиотеки, программист сможет подключать только `ilog.h`. Он и не знает о `baseLog.h` (доступ к этому классу скрыт).**

Comment: Это можем назвать имитацией виртуального конструктора(виртуальных конструкторов не бывает). Часто ли используется,  не могу сказать, но это еще один полезный подход. Лично я (не работаю программистом) использовал пару раз.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я правильно ли понимаю, что этот принцип также используется и тогда, когда программист не хочет, при малейших изменениях в классе `Log`, повторно компилировать и те файлы, где используется этот класс ?

Comment: Нет, достаточно просто класс написать в отдельном файле, но не скрытым от пользователя, чтобы при изменении в классе  перекомпилировался только этот файл. Просто таким образом скрываем реализацию класса + разгружаем интерфейс, чтобы пользователю не нужно было разобраться   в сущности класса(иногда таких скрытых классов может быть много) + код становится компактней и понятней. Конечно нужно помнить, что каждая задача требует свой подход, и  этот прием не используешь повсеместно.

Comment: Недостатки : нет возможности хранить объект статически *(как локальный, в стеке, в векторе, как временный объект)*, с неизвестным его размером. Идея интересная, но проще всё сделать на Си и не париться. Я бы сделал открытую структуру. Статические публичные функции и вуаля.

Comment: Не понимаю, это какая-то специфика qt? Реализация ILog::createInstance где-нибудь существует?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/MMjv81

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что на самом деле тут обычная инкапсуляция, прикрытая фабричным методом

Comment: @vp_arth  реализация `ILog` нет в `qt`. Это всего лишь пример реализации, которую видел не раз. Хочу поблагодарить за предоставленную Вами ссылку. Благодаря этой ссылке я заметил, что допустил ошибку в своем коде (она уже исправлена).

Comment: Если теперь функцию `createInstance` в simplelog.cpp заменить на метод `ILog::createInstance`, то мне будет всё понятно =)

Comment: @vp_arth Вы правы :) Спешил и не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это просто вынос фабричного метода `ILog::createInstance` в единицу трансляции связанную с реализацией интерфейса.

Плюс в том, что можно переключать реализацию просто заменив объектный файл на другой при линковке.

Минус в том, что невозможно в одной программе использовать более одной реализации интерфейса, возникнет конфликт.

---

Более каноничная реализация фабричного метода предполагает параллельную иерархию конструирующих классов с общим абстрактным предком.
Предельно упрощённо:

```cpp
class ILog {public: virtual void log() = 0; virtual ~ILog()=default;};
class ILogCreator {public: virtual ILog* create() = 0; virtual ~ILogCreator()=default;};

class LogA: public ILog {public: void log();};
void LogA::log() { std::cout << "A::log()\n";}

class LogACreator: public ILogCreator {public: ILog* create();};
ILog* LogACreator::create() { return new LogA();}

int main()
{
    ILogCreator* logCreator = new LogACreator();
    ILog* log = logCreator->create();
    log->log();

    delete log;
    delete logCreator;
}
```

Программист может не знать о деталях порождаемого класса, только о порождающем.

Comment: Чтобы устранить этот недостаток (_минус заключается в том, что невозможно использовать более одной реализации интерфейса в одной программе_), можно также добавить дополнительные методы, которые в свою очередь будут отвечать за определенный класс. Я добавил описанный пример в качестве кода к этому вопросу. Я думаю, что это может решить этот недостаток :)

Comment: Тем не менее - это остаётся одной реализацией интерфейса, разнесённой по частям в разные объектные файлы =) Скажем, нельзя переключать реализации AudioSettings в runtime, в зависимости, скажем, от cli параметров. Ну или придётся расширить портянку и создавать разными методами.  Но место своё концепт занимает, безусловно.

Comment: Я согласен. Но на счет `runtime` не может быть и речи. Это совсем другая история =)

Answer (score 0):

Это шаблон проектирования [фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

1. Позволяет создавать экземпляры неизвестного типа, при условии что тип - наследник интерфейса.
2. Скрывает реализацию от пользователя. Без этого шаблона пользователь имеет информацию о структуре и размере экземпляров класса - обычно лишнюю.

Из второго пункта есть следствия: пользователи класса не зависят от деталей его реализации - их не нужно перекомпилировать при изменении класса, только при изменении интерфейса. Код пользователей перекомпилируется реже и компилируется быстрее.

Comment: А как вызов ILog::createInstance становится вызовом SimpleLog::createInstance?

Comment: Например: `ILog *ILog::createInstance() { return SimpleLog::createInstance(); }`

Comment: Но SimpleLog, как утверждается, недоступен для подключения. В какой единице трансляции этот код?

Comment: Он скомпилирован заранее и помещён в библиотеку которая поставляется вместе с заголовком ilog.h. Иначе говоря линковщик будет видеть реализацию (и это неизбежно), а компилятор не будет.